# Paginate causes crashing in Laravel 4

Tags: laravel-4, query-builder, pagination

I am learning about Laravel 4 and I'm trying its pagination. I created a simple query to test the pagination, yet it always end up hanging. If I use `get()`, it works fine, but when I replace `get()` with `paginate()`, it hangs. Here is my code:

```
DB::table("samp_tbl")
    ->select("id","activity")
    ->whereNull("deleted_at")
    ->orderBy("id","desc")
    ->paginate(5);
```

Could someone tell me what's wrong with my code?

Comment: Your code looks okay at a glance. Does the page seem to load for a long time, or just loads a blank page? Don't know if anyone can be much help without some sort of error response. If it just loads a blank page, make sure error reporting is turned on properly.

Comment: @Cryode the page loads for a long time until the browser will stop responding, so I don't really know what causes the error. For now, I'll use the pagination with Eloquent until I figure out what causes the crashing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone else comes across this issue it's because you are using orderBy. In the Note: area on this page http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/pagination#usage it explains that laravel has issues with groupBy. However I also would assume this would go for orderBy as well. Writing a custom query would be recommended in your case.

Answer (score -2):

create a model for your database and it will work fine

Comment: This doesn't answer the question at all.